# Discord js получение имён серверов в которых состоит бот

Tags: javascript, бот, discord

Мне нужно получить список имён серверов в которых состоит бот.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [официальной документации](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds).
Например так:

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
  console.log(`${guild.name} | ${guild.id}`);
})
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: @СергейКузелин Благодарности принимаются в виде принятия ответа, слева от ответа галочкой.